# Парсинг параметров с помощью Regex

Tags: c#, .net, регулярные-выражения, парсер

Есть строка - ответ от веб сервера, приблизительно такого содержания

```
parameter0=213123123&parameter1=abcd&parameter2=vdv3123cdc
```

Как можно с помощью регулярных выражений вытащить значение параметра?
Попробовал следующим образом: `var regex = new Regex(@"parameter0=.*?(&|\r\n)");`

Но в данном случае вернет **parameter0=213123123&**, по идее необходимо вытащить только значение. И к сожалению данный вариант не найдет parameter2.

Comment: у вас задача такая сделать это с помощью регулярок? Или почему вы не используете для этого предназначенные для этих целей классы?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Используйте для задач соответствующие инструменты([`System.Web.HttpUtility`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility(v=vs.110).aspx))

```
string q = "parameter0=213123123&parameter1=abcd&parameter2=vdv3123cdc";

var result = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(q);
Console.WriteLine(result["parameter2"]);
```

> The `ParseQueryString` method uses UTF8 format to parse the query string
>   In the returned NameValueCollection, URL-encoded characters are
>   decoded and multiple occurrences of the same query string parameter
>   are listed as a single entry with a comma separating each value.

То есть вдобавок при этом параметры ваши будут декодированы (а-ля `%20`и т.п.), а повторяющиеся объединены через запятую.

Answer (score 3):

В таких простых случаях решение без регекспов будет гораздо понятнее и читабельнее, например:

```
var s = "parameter0=213123123&parameter1=abcd&parameter2=vdv3123cdc";
var parameters = s.Split('&')
                  .Select(pair => pair.Split('='))
                  .ToDictionary(pair => pair[0], pair => pair[1]);
Console.WriteLine(parameters["parameter0"]);
```

Сплитим по `&`, затем каждый кусок сплитим по `=`, первый элемент берем как ключ, второй - как значение. На выходе словарь, в котором можно по ключу искать значение.

Comment: Спасибо большое, даже не подумал об этом способе.